# Java main method argument handling, depending on user input

Tags: java, arrays, arguments, program-entry-point

I would like to know to know how do i compare the arguments passed into a java main method.

```
eg java hello -i
```

I tried printing args[0] and it does indeed gives me -i. however what i want to achieve is:

```
if args.length == 0 {
  do something
}
else if args[0] =="-i"{
  do something
}
```

However i keep getting index out of bound exception. is there anyway to convert the string in the string array args to just a string type so i can compare it?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  if args.length == 0 {
    do something
  }
  else if args[0] =="-i"
    do something
  } 


}
```

for example if they start the program without any arguments, i will call init() method. but if they entered -i as arguments, i will call install() instead..

Comment: You need to show us the **actual code**.

Comment: To check for String equality you must use `equals`. Also, in the `else` clause you use `arg` instead of `args`.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but don't compare Strings using '=='. That compares the reference; use `"-i".equals(args[0])`.

Comment: Because writing this sort of code is tedious, numerous developers have created their own library class to handle arguments to the `main` method. My own library class can be found [on Github](https://github.com/Bobulous/uk.org.bobulous.java.startup) and would allow you to simply specify that a flag called "i" was permitted, and then allow you to check whether it was provided or not when your Java application was called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you've given wouldn't even compile, but this *does* work:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("No arguments!");
        } else if (args[0].equals("-i")) {
            System.out.println("-i passed");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Something else");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that it's important that you're using `else` here - this would fail, for example:

```
if (args.length == 0) {
    System.out.println("No arguments!");
}
if (args[0].equals("-i")) {
    System.out.println("-i passed");
}
```

at that point you're checking `args[0]` *even if the length of the array is 0*. Given that you've given pseudo-code at the moment (no brackets round the conditions) I wonder whether that's the problem in your real code.

(Also note the use of `equals` instead of `==` as others have already pointed out.)

Comment: thanks.. i know its an amateurish question.. have been coding in asp.net for 3 years and my java has gotten so rusty..

Comment: @JohnMarston: The difference between Java and C# explains the `==` vs `equals`, but it doesn't explain why you got an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - *were* you just missing the `else`?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to convert the string in the string array args to just a string type so I can compare it?

You don't need to convert it.  However, you *do* need to compare it the right way; e.g.

```
if (args.length == 0) {
   // do something
} else if (args[0].equals("-i")) {
   // do something else 
}
```

(If you use `==` to compare strings, you are likely to get into trouble.  The `==` operator tests to see if two references point to the same object.  What you actually need is to see if two strings contain the same characters ... and you need to use the `equals` method to do that.)

---

However, this doesn't explain why you were getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.  I'd need to see **real** code to answer that.

Answer (score 0):

When comparing strings you need to use the *equals()* method as the *==* compare if they are the same string (not same as if they are equal).

Here's an example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length == 0) {
        System.err.println("No arguments");
    } else if (args.length == 1) {
        if (args[0].equals("first")) {
            System.err.println("The argument equals 'first'");
        } else {
            System.err.println("Don't know what you want with " + args[0]);
        }
    } else {
        System.err.println("Will not use the arguments");
        for (String arg: args) {
            System.err.println(arg);
        }
    }
}
```

Try calling it with no arguments, the argument first or any other arguments.